# An exclamation for “this is what I was looking for”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, exclamations

I am looking for an exclamation for a situation like the following:

> You are disappointed for what there is or you already have, and then
> you unexpectedly find/discover something that is so different and is truly
> pleasant for you.

In such a situation you might say ‘this is what I was looking for for so long’, or ‘this is what I wanted all the time’, ‘this is my thing’, and alike.

I can think of ‘wow’. But I am looking to see if there is any other ones.

Comment: _Eureka!_ is the classic Greek,  meaning 'I have found it'.

Comment: If you want synonymous exclamations, reasonable research would be to look up 'wow' in a thesaurus.

Comment: This question is not asking for a synonym: "wow" is merely proposed as a suggestion (and is too general, anyway). There is no real reason for closing it.

Comment: (Doesn't anybody say "Voila!", anymore?)

Comment: @Oldbag "Voila" is not suited for this sort of situation because it _can't_ be inferred from its use that the person speaking had been yearning for something special that had remained as yet out of reach. ([voila](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voil%C3%A0): —used to call attention, to express satisfaction or approval, or to suggest an appearance as if by magic). What is needed is a term that suggests satisfaction and  something of an appearance as if by magic, but on top of that, that suggests that there is in the appearance the answer to a quest that went on for some time.

Comment: @LPH (a) There is no research presented. OP states that 'Wow' is one possibility, so single word answers are acceptable, so at least a thesaurus search would be expected. (b) If the question is far broader, accepting all sorts of reasonable responses, it is too broadly scoped for ELU. 'That's it!' is hardly ELU material.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, there is not much research, but the case is one for which research yields little. "Wow" is seen as a possibility by the OP, but what is being asked is an exclamation, and that is not necessarily a one word term. The question _is narrower_ than as answered by means of "wow", which is, as far as I can see, but an aproximation that does not correspond to the definition  ("You are disappointed[…] what I wanted all the time’, […]."). In fact, this definition, which is what the inquirer should go by, is precise enough and does point to something like "That's  it!"  (1/2)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in my opinion. At the same time it invalidates all sorts of possibilities that have been put forth, this being so because they correspond more or less well to "Wow!". So, I think that the question is sufficiently focused, and that it is truly a question about usage. (2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*That's it*!" is typical in this situation.

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/that-is-it))  **that is it** You use that's it to indicate that nothing more needs to be done or that the end has been reached.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dime_Dialogues/GA1EAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22that%27s+it!%22&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover)) That's it ! That's it ! That's jest the thing ! We used to do that when I was a boy .

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Kindergarten/pcoNAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22that%27s+it!%22&dq=%22that%27s+it!%22&printsec=frontcover)) That's it! Like that, like that! But make more noise! (MICO starts to enjoy himself He's now eating huge spoonfuls, euphorically .) That's it, that's it! (To MECHE.) Look, Meche! Have you ever seen anything like it?

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Saturday_Evening_Post/OAczhknAAr0C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22that%27s+it!%22&dq=%22that%27s+it!%22&printsec=frontcover)) "That's it! That's it! That's it! That's the very word I never can find the right words. None of them are real". He jumped to his feet. "But that's the real word, the one I wanted to say, only I couldn't get it out, though it was on the tip of my tongue. […]."

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/That_s_a_Great_Idea/UJdZAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22that%27s+it!%22&dq=%22that%27s+it!%22&printsec=frontcover)) That's it ! The concept strikes you like a lightning bolt. It's a true time-saver.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal response to a birthday present is, "This is just what I've always wanted!" So now, let's vary that a bit for your situation: "This is just what I've been looking for!" or "Bingo!  Hit the nail on the head!"

Comment: Bingo is the best one-word expression of finding an object. "Where is it, ..., where is it, ..., bingo!"  You hit the nail on the head with that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these

- Aha!
- Eureka!
- Good Heavens!
- My word!

If you want to go in another direction, you could try:

- This is a godsend!
- Gotcha!